# Characteristic function of the gamma distribution

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The characteristic function of the gamma distribution with shape $\alpha>0$ and rate $\beta>0$ is given by
$$
\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{\left( 1-\frac{ix}{\beta} \right)^{\alpha}}, \quad x\in \mathbb{R}.
$$
I am wondering why is raising the complex number in the denominator to the power $\alpha>0$ well-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless $\alpha$ is an integer, it's not well-defined as such, but by convention one uses the principal branch of the logarithm when that's applicable and nothing else is explicitly stated. Since
$$\operatorname{Re} \biggl(1 - \frac{ix}{\beta}\biggr) = 1$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the principal branch is applicable, and we can unambiguously write
$$\varphi(x) = \exp \biggl(-\alpha\operatorname{Log}\biggl(1 - \frac{ix}{\beta}\biggr)\biggr)\,,$$
where $\operatorname{Log}$ denotes the principal branch of the logarithm.

Since we need $\varphi(0) = 1$ for a characteristic function, the principal branch is the *only* admissible choice to define the power, thus in context the power is well-defined, although viewed in isolation it isn't.

Comment: So should the formula in my question be understood only as a shorthand for the formula that you wrote?

Comment: Essentially, unless the exponent is an integer, $a^b$ is (for $a \neq 0$) always just a shorthand for $\exp (b\log a)$. Which of the infinitely many logarithms of $a$ is used in that needs to be stated, or deduced via convention.